# How to validate the date such that it is after today in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I have an Active Record model that contains attributes: expiry_date. How do I go about validating it such that it is after today(present date at that time)? I am totally new to Rails and ruby and I couldn't find a similar question answering exactly this?

I am using Rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your question is (almost) exactly answered [in the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods).

Here's the example code they give. This class validates that the date is in the *past*, while your question is how to validate that the date is in the *future*, but adapting it should be pretty easy:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if expiration_date.present? && expiration_date < Date.today
      errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")
    end
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's the code to set up a custom validator:

```
#app/validators/not_in_past_validator.rb
class NotInPastValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.blank?
      record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "can't be blank")
    elsif value <= Time.zone.today
      record.errors.add attribute,
                        (options[:message] || "can't be in the past")
    end
  end
end
```

And in your model:

```
validates :signed_date, not_in_past: true
```

Comment: I think `in_future` is nicer

Comment: @Koen. in_future looks nicer, but what's more important, not_in_past and in_future are not exactly interchangeable: `value <= Time.zone.today` is equivalent of in_future, so if this validator is called not_in_past, the logic should change to `value < Time.zone.today`

Answer (score 9):

The simplest and working solution is to use the in-built validation from Rails. Just validates it like that:

```
validates :expiry_date, inclusion: { in: (Date.today..Date.today+5.years) }
```

Comment: watch out - those dates will be fixed to when the code was loaded (i.e. the rails instance started)

Comment: then replace with `in: ->(date) { (Date.today..Date.today+5.years) }`

Comment: with ruby 2.6 can it be ```in: ->(date) { (Date.today..) }```

Comment: When testing with shoulda_matchers use allow_value and not validates_inclusion_of because of they can't get a max value for the range.

Answer (score 6):

I took @dankohn answer, and updated to be I18n ready. I also removed the `blank` test, because that's not the responsibility of this validator, and can easily be enabled by adding `presence: true` to the validates call.

The updated class, now named `in_future`, which I think is nicer than `not_in_past`

```
class InFutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, (options[:message] || :in_future)) unless in_future?(value)
  end

  def in_future?(date)
    date.present? && date > Time.zone.today
  end
end
```

Now add the `in_future` key to your localization file.

For all fields under `errors.messages.in_future`, e.g. for Dutch:

```
nl:
  errors:
    messages:
      in_future: 'moet in de toekomst zijn'
```

Or per field under `activerecord.errors.models.MODEL.attributes.FIELD.in_future`, e.g. for the `end_date` in a `Vacancy` model in Dutch:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        vacancy:
          attributes:
            end_date:
              in_future: 'moet in de toekomst zijn'
```

Comment: When I do this I get: Unknown validator: 'InFutureValidator'

Comment: Where did you save this file? I suggest you save it under `app/validators/in_future_validator.rb`

Comment: Pretty much exactly the same, except maybe that I use DateTime and I am running Rails 5.

Comment: Dank je wel! Het werkt, en ik weet niet wat ik eerst verkeerd had gedaan. Misschien was het dat ik de server moest herstarten? IT WORKS :)

Comment: @Code-MonKy if this answer was of any help to you, please upvote it by clicking the "Up" arrow

Answer (score 4):

In rails 4+ there are `future?` and `past?` methods for `DateTime` objects, so a simpler answer is

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if expiration_date.present? && expiration_date.past?
      errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")
    end
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I gathered a few things from the other posts to get my answer, but I think my result may be a little more straight forward than creating a separate validator method or class, which I think we can get around for a relatively simple validation.

- I used the `proc` so that it would load the time when the validation is run and not when the class is loaded. There were also some suggestions that gave a lambda (`->(data)`), but this requires you to act like there is an argument when you don't actually need one.
- For me, I didn't want it to throw a validation error if nothing was updated so I also added `if: :changed?` so that there's only a validation error if something about the record was being updated. If you wanted to do a specific field or even just the timestamp field, you can use the rails method by combining the field name and `changed?` - ex. `:my_cool_timestamp_attribute_changed?`
- The error message was a little non specific, so it helped to make a custom one. Without adding the message, it comes back as `... is not included in the list`.
- In my case, I was only worried about updates (and not initial creation) being possibly set in the past, so I have `on: :update`. [The rails default is to validate on both create and update](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on).

```
  validates(
    :my_cool_timestamp_attribute,
    inclusion: {
      in: proc { Time.current.. },
      message: "must be in the future when updating",
      if: :changed?
    },
    on: :update,
  )
```