# How to validate uniqueness of date portion of datetime data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Could someone please guide me on the subject specified in title,
I have tried google as well as [validate date portion of datetime entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512691/how-to-validate-the-date-such-that-it-is-after-today-in-rails)
for example there is a date portion in the column a value=> **Wed, 08 Jul 2015 06:19:00 UTC +00:00** 
and I want to check prior to creation of a new record that the column mydate(data type: datetime) with a similar date a does not exists in the database. in this case date portion of **mydate if it is Wed, 08 Jul 2015**  should not be saved.
How would you implement the date validation portion of the datatype **datetime**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @jurgemaister hi, I am so sorry for the confusion, thank you for taking the time to correct my mistake and grooming me to be professional, I have edited my post to improve its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `before_create` callback, replace `Model` and `field` with respective model and datetime field

```
before_create :check_date

def check_date
   unless Model.where(field: field.to_date.beginning_of_day..field.to_date.end_of_day).blank?
     return false
   else
     return true
   end
end
```